# How to exclusive a set from a large set in R

Tags: r

Suppose that I have a set of `10` elements. Suppose that my code is able to choose only `3` elements at a time. Then, I would like it to choose another $3$ elements, however, without selecting the elements that are already selected.

```
x <- c(4,3,5,6,-2,7,-4,10,22,-12)
```

Then, suppose that my condition is to select `3` elements that are less than `5`. Then,

```
new_x <- c(4, 3, -2)
```

Then, I would like to select another `3` elements that are less than 5 but were not selected at the first time. If there is no `3` element then the third element should have value zero.

Hence,

```
new_xx <- c(-4,-12,0)
```

Any help, please?

Comment: How are these elements to be selected? At random? In the order they occur?

Comment: @MauritsEvers in the order they occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `split`

```
f <- function(x, max = 5, n = 3) {
    x <- x[x < max]
    ret <- split(x, rep(1:(length(x) / n + 1), each = n)[1:length(x)])
    lapply(ret, function(w) replace(rep(0, n), 1:length(w), w))
}

f(x)
#$`1`
#[1]  4  3 -2
#
#$`2`
#[1]  -4 -12   0
```

Explanation: We define a custom function that first selects entries < 5, then splits the resulting vector into chunks of length 3 and stores the result in a `list`, and finally 0-pads those `list` elements that are vectors of length < 3.

### Sample data

```
x <- c(4,3,5,6,-2,7,-4,10,22,-12)
```